# How to use ado.net reader?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

How can i read only one record, when i want all records its fine but when i need a specific record with @id, my while loop jums out ?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteArticle(int ProductID)
{
    int id = ProductID;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
           string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdminServices"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                connection.Open();

               //delete from database
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM MyTable  WHERE id = @id", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                 //read imagePathe from Database from database
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = @id", connection))
                {

                    command.Parameters.Add("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read()) // --> here it skips while loop ????
                    {

                        string ImagePath = (string)reader["DbImagePath"];

                    }

                }

            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, make sure your query is actually returning any rows.

Comment: @D Stanley,How can i read only one record, when i want all records its fine but when i need a specific record with @id, my while loop jums out ?

Comment: Are you trying to delete it then read it? You're using the same product ID

Comment: @JohnGibb, i did, i check if there is a id = x, and there is, but it seams that reader will not read???

Comment: @LukeHutton, hmmm... I guess the reader doesnt read beacouse the record is already deleted.....

Comment: when did you check if it exists? because you delete it and then try to read it.

Comment: You can just read the imagePath before you do the delete query. Are you trying to delete the image as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while (reader.Read()) { }` will break when there are no more records to read. Since your first command deletes the record identified by `id`, there will never be anything to read with that id.

Answer (score 3):

How's the second query suppose to returns anything if you delete the row with the first one?

Comment: Thanks guys, i think i sholud switch actions on this one :-)

Comment: sometimes we overthink the problem and miss the obvious error - we've all been there :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `SqlDataReader` correctly.  The only reason it should skip that while loop is if you don't get back any records.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample

```
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";

    using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command =
            new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        // Call Read before accessing data.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader[0], reader[1]));
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```